# How to save part_id in Association has and belongs to many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Model

```
class Assembly < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book
  has_and_belongs_to_many :parts
end
```

Join table

```
class CreateJoinTableAssemblyPart < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_join_table :assemblies, :parts, id: false do |t|
      t.index [:assembly_id, :part_id]
      t.index [:part_id, :assembly_id]
    end
  end
end
```

Schema

```
create_table "assemblies_parts", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "assembly_id", null: false
  t.integer "part_id", null: false
  t.integer "assemblies"
  t.integer "parts"
end
```

Controller

```
def create
  @assembly = Assembly.new(assembly_params)
```

```
def assembly_params
  params.require(:assembly).permit(:book_id, :part_id)
```

_Form.html

```
<div class="form-inputs">
  <%= f.association :book %>
  <%= f.association :parts %>
</div>
```

This way saves only the book_id

I need to save the part_id but it doesn't save and it doesn't even give an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to whitelist the correct param key and an array of permitted scalar values - not a single value:

```
def assembly_params
  params.require(:assembly)
        .permit(:book_id, part_ids: [])
end
```

Check the logs for the correct param key to use.

Also remove the `assemblies` and `parts` columns from the `assemblies_parts` table. You don't need them and it just seems like an open invitation for bugs.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I had already done this from the error.
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)

Comment: You have to remember that I'm not looking over your shoulder and can't see the code you're working on. An argument error is one the most generic errors possible and it tells me absolutely nothing - except that its not coming from the code in this answer.